# More or less accurate online tool to estimate other's website traffic

Tags: tools, web-traffic

I am looking for a free online traffic estimation tool. I have seen [statshow](http://www.statshow.com), [WebDetail](http://webdetail.org) and [Yandaloo](http://www.yandalo.com/), but they are giving quite different results for a given URL.

Can anyone recommend a tool providing more or less accurate estimations of traffic for a given URL? Thanks.

**P.S.:** Else, can someone check their website against the result provided by those tools and tell whether anyone is close to reality? Thanks.

Comment: Estimate your site traffic or another site's traffic? Yours you can get from your stats. Other sites' you can't get accurate estimations for.

Comment: I have updated the question. It is for 'other' sites. Are you saying there is absolutely no valid tool online to provide an estimation of the traffic?

Comment: You can get estimations, they'll just be inaccurate. How can you get another's site's traffic levels without access to their stats?

Comment: The tools I have found so far seem to rely on public data...

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data is public. Site stats are private. After that its information gleaned from spyware or just guesses.

Comment: Like @JohnConde said you will not find accurate data on another websites traffic. Alexa was the first to offer some stats like this but based it off of IE coming with their toolbar bundled way back when and counting how many people visited websites which wasn't exactly accurate. Unless you have access to someones analytics account(s) or raw access logs your guess is as good as any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some research and there seems to be a company doing proper statistical research from about 2 millions real US users: [compete.com](http://www.compete.com/us/about/our-data/).

**Update**

StatShow and Google's AdPlanner are doing a good to great job too. I keep an updated note [here](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-estimate-another-websites.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how accurate this is, but my spider sense tells me that [quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/) is pretty good